# Edit manifest file of chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am a beginner and trying to make an extension for chrome. 
I have a `manifest.json` file and I want to edit this file interactively. This means that a user will enter the information and my `manifest.json` file should change accordingly. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you saying you would like to interactive with a user who has your extension installed and allow them to make changes to the manifest.json on the fly?  I don't think that can be done.  If that is not the correct scenario please respond so we might get a better idea of your intentions.

Comment: This is not possible. If you need to dynamically edit permissions, you should have `manifest.json` provide the greatest level of privilege that will ever be needed by your app, and then programmatically enforce permission constraints within your application.

Comment: Thnx i can understand the problem above now the problem is How can i run a script for every page opened . I want to do it using background.html .I already tried to run document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', exec_fun); and also registered backgroung.html in manifest.json to execute exec_fun() function .But it is not working .
Help !!

Answer (score -2):

You can execute scripts on any page using **Content Scripts**. Just set the matches value to `*`:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html